# NextGen Plugin: on finding images tags

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to understand (and find) where nextgen save images tags. I tried in ngg_picture table without any result ...

Do u know where they are? Are they some kind of standard wordpress tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextGen uploads your images basically as [Attachment Post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments). This means that the tags themselves are stored in the `wp_terms` table

Comment: Do u know how to save an image tags from custom code? Does it exist any NextGen API to do that or do I have to write down SQL query ad hoc?

Comment: Can you provide more details about WHERE and how you are trying to insert tags. Maybe update the question with your custom tag code.